# Passportjs with MySQL in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, passport.js

Hi everyone i try to connect to a MySQL database to authenticate the user through `passport.js`, I do not know what's wrong in my source code. When I gave correct or wrong user and password information it results in a redirect failure. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? I am new to this.

Here is my source code:

```
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username,password,done){
   connection.query("select * from userinfo where UserName='"+username+"'     ",function(err,user){
    if(err)
    {
        return done(err);           
    }
    if(!user)
    {
        return done(null,false,{message: 'Incorrect user name'});           
    }
    if(user.password != password)
    {
       return done(null,false,{message: 'Incorrect password'});
    }

    return done(null,user);     

   });
}
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user);
});

app.post('/validates', passport.authenticate('local',{successRedirect: '/productdisplay', failureRedirect: '/validate', failureFlash: true }));
```

and also the flash message is not working. Please tell me, I almost spent a lot of time in this and I am not get any error. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Try to put some console.log messages in there to see what section of your code it is entering. Also where is your express.cookie stuff? Take a look at the example on https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport

Comment: thank you for your reply.i got cookie parser and session middleware in above of the app.use(flash());. first problem i just put only return done(null,false,{message: 'Incorrect user name'});  i am not even get the flash message. any idea give me guide me to solve this issue first.

Comment: thanks for your console.log options i solve that issue.

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it, what was the issue after all?

Comment: i just access the MYSQL return data user[0]. i got the user information. i checked this using json.stringfy().

Comment: gotcha, not sure I follow but you're on your way and that's the important thing

Answer (score 0):

to serialize user you need to send user.id not user

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});
```

check this gist [Passport js with MySQL](https://gist.github.com/manjeshpv/84446e6aa5b3689e8b84)

Check out full node application [Passport js with MySQL](https://github.com/manjeshpv/node-express-passport-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Serializing and deserializing a user is not trivial as you have it.  You should serialize the user by `user.id` and deserialize it by doing a lookup for that user by the `id` given.

As a side note, make sure you are salting passwords before storing them in a database.  Plain text passwords being stored is a big no-no.